# How to pack side by side in tkinter with 3 radiobuttons and 1 Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my current output:
**Output Image:**
[image: Output Image]

This is my desired output only using pack (Used paint to re-create my desired output):
**Desired image:**
[image: Desired image]

How can this be achieved by using pack?

Here's my current code:

```
    #Seperated into tabs
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)

    notebook.pack(expand = 1, fill = "both")
    #Frames
    main = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(main, text='Main-Screen') #Main screen

    left = ttk.Frame(main)
    left.pack(side = "left", expand = True, fill = 'y')

    right = ttk.Frame(main)
    right.pack(side = "right", expand = True, fill = 'y')

    self.info = ["test one", "test two", "test three"
             ]

    self.vars = []
    for idx,i in enumerate(self.info):
        self.var = IntVar(value=0)
        self.vars.append(self.var)
        self.lblOption = Label(main,text=i)
        self.btnYes = Radiobutton(right, text="Yes", variable=self.var, value=2)
        self.btnNo = Radiobutton(right, text="No", variable=self.var, value=1)
        self.btnNa = Radiobutton(right, text="N/A", variable=self.var,value=0)
        self.lblOption.pack(anchor = 'w')
        self.btnYes.pack(side = 'left')
        self.btnNo.pack(side = 'left')
        self.btnNa.pack(side = 'left')
```

Comment: ***"pack side by side in tkinter with 3 radiobuttons and 1 Label?"***: Use a **own** `Frame` for every group `Label` and 3 `Radiobutton`'s

Comment: Would it be possible to separate the left notebook and right notebook with grid and pack managers?

Comment: Read about [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like the below. Create 3 separate `Frame` in the `for` loop, and in each `Frame` packs your widgets with side set to left.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

vars_list = []

for i in ["test one", "test two", "test three"]:
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    tk.Label(frame,text=i).pack(side="left")
    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    vars_list.append(var)
    tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="Yes", variable=var, value=2).pack(side="left")
    tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="No", variable=var, value=1).pack(side="left")
    tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="N/A", variable=var,value=0).pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```